# Mouse follower easing in/out

Tags: mouse, easing, acceleration

There are a lot of mousefollower tutorials out there. Most of them feature a simple formula for easing the motion:

```
x += (tx - x) / interp;
y += (ty - y) / interp;
```

(tx = target position, x = actual position, interp > 1)

This makes the follower go very fast in the beginning, then decelerate slowly to the target position.

How do i have to change the formular, so that i can define a custom acceleration, custom deceleration and a maxspeed for the movement in between? For the very beginning i'd be happy with an added acceleration at all.

Thanks!

Hans

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is the change in velocity over time.  So in 1D, to apply a constant velocity, you'd do:

```
v += a * dt;
x += v * dt;
```

where:

- `a` is the acceleration (a constant)
- `v` is the velocity
- `x` is the x-position
- `dt` is the timestep, i.e. the time between updates

You'd do something similar for deceleration, except that `a` would now be negative.

To set a maximum velocity, you simply need to a conditional check on `v`, maybe:

```
v = MIN(v_max, v);
```

where `v_max` is your maximum allowed velocity (a constant).

In 2D, you'd need to take into account the direction of travel:

```
x += v * cos(theta);
y += v * sin(theta);
```

I'll leave it to you to calculate `theta`...